# How to unquote nested json?

Tags: json, quoting

I'm dealing with an API that returns JSON with various string fields - some of which are quoted JSON. This JSON may in turn contain string fields with double quoted JSON etc.

It's a giant pain to read this data because no formatting tool will properly work on the quoted JSON. Is there a tool (command line or otherwise) that can recursively walk my JSON and unquote any string fields containing valid JSON?

Comment: Could you give an example of a JSON formatted like that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try recursively re parse your JSON (reparse until nothing change anymore):

```js
var jsonWithQuotedJson = "{ \"a\": 1, \"b\": \"string\", \"c\": [2,\"otherString\"], \"d\": { \"e\": { \"a\": 1, \"b\": \"somestring\", \"c\": \"{ \\\"quotedJsonKey\\\": 42 }\" } } }";

var somethingChanged = false;

function reparse(obj) {
    if(Array.isArray(obj)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            obj[i] = reparse(obj[i]);
        }
        return obj;
    } else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            obj[keys[i]] = reparse(obj[keys[i]]);
        }
        return obj;
    } else {
        try {
            var res = JSON.parse(obj);
            // maybe a string as been turned into a new object?
            if (res !== obj) {
              somethingChanged = true;
              return res;
            }
            return obj;
        } catch (error) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
var res = JSON.parse(jsonWithQuotedJson);
do {
    somethingChanged = false;
    // just to log the progession of decoding
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)));
    res = reparse(res);
} while (somethingChanged);

console.log(res);
```